# Command to power off (not reset) module in Cisco 4500?

Tags: cisco

Came across a situation where powering off a module in a Cisco 4500 (Sup7-E) would have been nice, but couldn't seem to find the command.  Ended up having to unseat the module until we had the fix in place and then someone had to go insert it again

Unfortunately, it was off site, so it required someone to go to the location to do this and it would have been nice to be able to do remotely.

I know with a 6500 you can do a `no power enable module <#>` (IOS) or `set module power down <#>` (CatOS) to power off the module, but just couldn't find it on the 4500.

Anyone have any suggestions or ideas?  Hidden command maybe?

Or can anyone confirm the platform doesn't have the capability (and why)?

It seems somewhat odd to me that the capability to do a reset (`hw-module [slot|module] <#> reset`) of a module exists, but no capability to power it off entirely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To power off a particular module, use `Switch(config)# no hw-module module _num_ power`; you can find that command on Page 20 of [this Cisco doc](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/15-1/XE_330SG/configuration/guide/config/pwr_envr.pdf)

FYI, there [isn't a graceful shutdown command for the whole switch](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11515966/power-cisco-core-switch).
You should backup your config (just in case), issue a reboot, wait till you can audibly hear a change in fan speed, and then remove power before system starts booting.

Comment: Not looking to shut down the entire switch.  Just a single module on the switch, while we keep the rest of the switch up and running.

Comment: sorry - I pasted the deep url rather than the command reference index.  Nevermind - I didn't find much there either.

Does `Switch(config)# no hw-module module _num_ power` work?

Try http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/15-1/XE_330SG/configuration/guide/config/pwr_envr.pdf  Page 20.

Comment: Dang...there it is.  I knew it had to be somewhere.  Please edit your answer to include both the reference and the command.

Answer (score 1):

or you could just type:

hw-module slot *num* reset power-cycle

but if a sup card and in rommon (message "Module not completely up") it does not want to play. (assuming its not my equipment)

.. off to site we go..

Answer (score 1):

"hw-module module x shutdown ", this command used to completely power down the particular module. Please do let me know.